# Laravel - add foreign key on existing table with data

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration, laravel-5.4

I have existing table `objects` with data. Now I need to add new table named `holdings` and add a relation from objects to `holdings` table. In the migration file, I print this:

```
$table->foreign('holding_id')->references('id')->on('holdings')->onDelete("NO ACTION");
```

and get this error when trying to migrate

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update 
a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kolomnaoffice`.`#sql-f10_126` 
CONSTRAINT `objects_holding_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`holding_id`) 
REFERENCES `holdings` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION) (SQL: alter table `objects` add constraint 
`objects_holding_id_foreign` foreign key (`holding_id`) references `holdings` 
(`id`) on delete NO ACTION)
```

I have correct database structure (both InnoDB), the fields exist and have correct type (int). The only thing different is that the table `objects` is filled with data, and table `holdings` is new and empty.

Comment: Try making it the column nullable

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `holding_id` column should be `unsigned`

Create a new migration file and migrate it, migration code should be like this :

```
Schema::table('objects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('holding_id')->unsigned()->change();

    $table->foreign('holding_id')->references('id')->on('holdings');
});
```

The `change()` method is called to change the structure of existing column.

It's not necessary to call `onDelete("NO ACTION")` method.

Comment: how about the down() function?. in case i need to rollback the migration?

Comment: change is for when there is a column before  but for exist table and data we need to add foreign key with null inex  like  ``[..] ->index()->nullable();``

Answer (score 10):

Thanks Mohammad but this solution didn't work for me as I am `Laravel 5.4` and have different case here that my other table is already exists, Here what I found may it help some one.

```
Schema::table('objects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('holding_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();

    $table->foreign('holding_id')->references('id')->on('holdings');
});
```

with `index()` and `nullable()` it made the trick.

**Edit**
No need for `index()` it just need to be `nullable()`

Comment: I wonder if a nullable foregin key is a good idea? correct me if i'm worong

Comment: @toing_toing in my case the table was full of data witch will make it very difficult to add a foreign key without a default value so `nullable()` can be a good solution, then if you like to change that latter when you change you data.

Answer (score 0):

To adding a foreign key, first make sure your column is marked as unsigned.

Just add a line before your line:

```
$table->integer('holding_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('holding_id')->references('id')->on('holdings')->onDelete("NO ACTION");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large table, say 1Million+ records, they I guess the best plan of operation is to:

- Create a field with unsigned int datatype
- Make sure new insertions to the table will follow to add value to the column. So change your insert queries accordingly
- Create a queue to update older records and run it
- After the the queue finishes, convert the field into foreign key