# Laravel 5 - Add column and foreign key to an existing table with data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am very new at Laravel! But I'm trying. Here is were I could use some help;

I have a posts table. I have a user table. But I forgot to add a foreign key in the posts table that links to the user id.

The create users table migration:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

The create posts table migration:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

I have created the new migration file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AlterTablePostsAddForeignUser extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
      Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
          // I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO DO NEXT
      });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to fill up the "public function up()" method here! If anyone can help! It will be much appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744733/laravel-add-foreign-key-on-existing-table-with-data

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and this worked for me.

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
 });
```

Here when you are trying to add foreign key, by default it will try to have a Null value for new user_id column of the existing posts records.This 'null referencing' may cause the issue because the Database will expects a value for it by default. Using `nullable()` foreign key will avoid that issue because we explicitly says to Database that this upcoming Foreign Key field may consist a NULL value.

In detail explanation - Before you create the foreign key in Posts table, there might be some existing records in posts table. Whenever you are trying to create a foreign key,the existing records in the posts will try to have a NULL value in their upcoming Foreign Key column (user_id) which is called as null reference. Null referencing is a Database violation because by default Database expects a value for a foreign key field. So the Database will throw an error in this case.

To avoid the error we explicitly says Database that we will allow NULL values for this certain foreign key column user_id, using the nullable() function. So when ever the migration happen successfully the existing records will have a NULL value in its foreign key field and the values can be add later on (Or we can leave it as null if needed)

Answer (score 1):

See the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#modifying-columns)

You need to install `doctraine/dbal` before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your  composer.json file. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to determine the current state of the column and create the SQL queries needed to make the specified adjustments to the column and the you should try what I found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744733/laravel-add-foreign-key-on-existing-table-with-data) SO post

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->change();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

`change()` method for change structure of column

after this run the artisan command

```
php artisan migrate
```

if this doesn't work for you shoot the comment here! :)

Comment: ok I have updated my answer try the updated answer first install doctraine/dbal and then do what I wrote in the answer I hope you will get rid of your problem :)

Comment: Then I get the error that there is no users_id column. SO I have changed the up() method;

    public function up()
    {
      Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
          $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
      });
    }

But now I get a constraint violation

Comment: run the command `php artisan migrate` also I have made the update in answer too :)

Comment: If I ditch the `->change()` part it does create the column but not create the index or the relationship. I get a constraint violation error.

Comment: check the type of your primary key  and make sure your foreign key should be unsigned.

Comment: it is unsigned! Both are unsiged. "id" in the users table and "user_id" in the posts table after it was created with the violation constraint. with running the migration

Comment: can you specify the error code and error msg you got??