# How make Laravel Migration for one to many and one to one for same table

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many

I have a problem
to make migration with relationship.

case :

- 1 Department will have many Employees
- 1 Employee belongTo 1 Department
- 1 Department will have one manager (from employees table)

Here is my migration

```
Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');

        $table->foreignId('manager_id')->nullable()
            ->references('id')->on('employees')
            ->nullOnDelete();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

---

```
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name', 255)->nullable();
    $table->string('picture', 1024)->nullable();

    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()
        ->references('id')->on('users')
        ->nullOnDelete();

    $table->foreignId('department_id')->nullable()
        ->references('id')->on('departments')
        ->nullOnDelete();

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

---

when I do php artisan migrate:fresh
it show up error :

```
    SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Foreign key
    'departments_manager_id_foreign' references invalid table 'employees'. 
    (SQL: alter table "departments" add constraint "departments_manager_id_foreign" foreign key ("manager_id")
    references "employees" ("id") on delete set null)
```

---

This because there is no employees table when trying to create departments.
But if I trying to create employees first, then no departments tables.

Any suggestion for my problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Create both tables, _then_ add the `foreignIdFor` as another `Schema::table()` call. You can have multiple instances of `Schema::create()` and `Schema::table()` methods in a single migration, or you can add another migration after both tables have been created, etc.

Comment: There are times When I already created the migration files then I happen to have the same error. I only change the table name then the file name. example `create_employees_table` I only change the `employees` part. Since laravel executing the migration file based on timestamp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - add foreign key on existing table with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744733/laravel-add-foreign-key-on-existing-table-with-data)

Answer (score 1):

as @TimLewis suggested in the comment, you can add the department table without foreign key first, then add the employees table and setup the foreign key for the departments table.

Department migration

```
Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('manager_id')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The employees migration

```
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name', 255)->nullable();
    $table->string('picture', 1024)->nullable();

    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()
        ->references('id')->on('users')
        ->nullOnDelete();

    $table->foreignId('department_id')->nullable()
        ->references('id')->on('departments')
        ->nullOnDelete();

    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::table('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('manager_id')->references('id')->on('employees')
            ->nullOnDelete();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments("id")->unsigned(false);
        $table->string('name');

        $table->unsignedInteger('manager_id')->value(11)->nullable(true);
        $table->foreign('manager_id')->references('id')->on('employees')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

```
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments("id")->unsigned(false);
    $table->string('name', 255)->nullable();
    $table->string('picture', 1024)->nullable();

    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->value(11)->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
     
    $table->unsignedInteger('department_id')->value(11)->nullable();
    $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

this should work

Comment: Migrations are run in the order of their filename's datetime, meaning  `Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) { // ...; $table->foreign('manager_id')->references('id')->on('employees')->onDelete('cascade'); ...` will not work; the `employees` table doesn't exist yet. If you reversed the order, you'd still have the same issue; `Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments')->onDelete('cascade');` the `departments` table doesn't exist yet in that case.